# in_array() not finding needle in haystack

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple `in_array` statement in PHP. It's looking for the this needle:

`926296884640412424_1534875699`

In this haystack:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 926296884640412424_1534875699
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 926301883885225094_723729160
        )
)
```

My code is like this:

```
if(!in_array($object->id, $Admin->hiddenItems, true)) {
   // Always fires
} else {
   // Never fires
}
```

And it never finds it. I've tried both with `strict` set to TRUE and FALSE, but neither works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a mulidimensional array

Comment: @JohnConde In the documentation you can use an array as the needle, I guess I assumed that meant it would also work with multidimensional array. Erk. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching in a multidimensional array. Flatten it before using in_array():

```
if (!in_array($object->id, array_column($Admin->hiddenItems, 'id'), true)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective. I'll remember the `array_column` function for the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arrays = array(
    array(
        'id' => '926296884640412424_1534875699'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '926301883885225094_723729160'
    )
);

print exist('926296884640412424_1534875699', $arrays);

function exist($id, $arrays) {
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        if (in_array($id, $array)) {
            return "exist";
        }
    }
    return "no exist";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this recursive function as well to search certain value in multidimensional arrays:

```
function multi_in_array_r($needle, $haystack) {
     if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($haystack as $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && multi_in_array_r($needle, $element))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}
```

It's up to you to decide what gives best results, because as you can see there are few different way to accomplish the same thing.